# How to import my graph in a toplevel widget in tkinter

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter, toplevel

I'm trying to import my matplotlib graph into my tkinter window using a topLevel widget but I recieve the 'pyimage10 does not exist error'. 
I want my plot inside the topLevel widget but currently have another whole window where the plot is created.

I've condensed the graphs.py code but can confirm it does successfully creates a graph

```
#graphs.py
def plot1(self):
    key = ['Sales Volume','Sales Revenue']
    index = np.arange(len(self.drinks))
    f = plt.figure(figsize=(7,5))
    plt.subplots_adjust(left=0.3,bottom=0.3)
    plt.bar(index+0,self.salesVolume1,color= 
    ('m','m'),align='center',width=.4)
    plt.bar(index+.40,self.salesRevenue1,color= 
    ('r','r'),align='center',width=.4)
    plt.legend(key, fontsize=12)
    plt.xlabel('Drinks', fontsize=10)
    plt.ylabel('Sales Volume / Revenue', fontsize=10)
    plt.xticks(index, self.drinks, fontsize=10, rotation=30)
    plt.title('Aggregate Sales Volume and Revenue')
    f.show()


#file.py
import graphs
import matplotlib
import tkinter as tk

matplotlib.use("TkAgg")
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg, 
NavigationToolbar2Tk
from matplotlib.figure import Figure


class PageThree(tk.Frame,graphs.Analytics2):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)


        canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(graphs.Analytics2, self)
        canvas.draw()
        canvas.get_tk_widget().pack()
```

When ran, it opens up my plot in a separate window which is not what im trying to do - im trying to embed it within a toplevel on another window, and my inttial tk window is not popping up now.

Comment: Remove `top = tk.Toplevel(self)` and `FigureCanvasTkAgg(graphs.Analytics2, top)` should `FigureCanvasTkAgg(graphs.Analytics2, self)`

Comment: Done - have edited code also.  But am getting same error 'pyimage10 does not exist error'.

Comment: Your `figure` reference is `f = plt.figure(...` but you pass `graphs.Analytics2` to `FigureCanvasTkAgg(graphs.Analytics2, self)`. You didnt show which type of object `graphs.Analytics2` is.